# Have a select element with an option element who's value is null instead of an empty string

Tags: html

Say I have the following `select` element:

```
<select>
    <option></option>
    <option>other stuff</option>
</select>
```

The value for the first option is "" (empty string).

**Is there something I can put in the HTML to say that the first value should be null instead of empty string?**

*Bit more detail then:*

I am using BreezeJs and it expects the values of this `select`'s `option`s to be breeze objects or null.  When it gets empty string it throws an error because the required properties are not present.

I can (and will) set this via javascript, but my actual situation makes that more complicated that it would seem at first glance.  I figured I would try to see if I could do it via HTML first.  My Google search did not indicate if it was possible either way.  So I put in the question on Stack Overflow.  From what I am seeing here, it seems like HTML does not have a way to say that the option is `null`.

Comment: Do you mind clarifying? What are you trying to do.

Comment: Seems like this would be more of a scripting language issue like JavaScript, PHP, etc.

Comment: @steve - I want the value of the first option to be null when selected.  (The javascript library that looks at the value expects either null or a specific type of object.  Empty string breaks that.)

Comment: I agree with j08691. This is a job for a scripting language. First, tell us what you are trying to do so we can help you.

Comment: @Vaccano if this library jobs to interact with dom elements, you should consider to open an issue on github for it. (if it has github page and maintained)